# Why is the sequel to "Smokey and the Bandit II" titled "Smokey and the Bandit Part 3"?

Tags: title, sequels, smokey-and-the-bandit

Or to put another way, why wasn't it just called "Smokey and the Bandit III"? Was this a studio mandate, an oversight, a joke? Why did the "Part" suddenly get thrown in?

Comment: This happens more than you might guess. Return of the Living Dead Part II (a sequel to a movie that had a "The" beginning the title) is followed by Return of the Living Dead 3. In two sequels, the title lost a "The" and a "Part" and roman numerals.

Comment: Because they don't want audiences to think that he's Ill